# azure aad (new directory) - doesnt show all menu items

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

[image]

Azure AAD / Registration Apps

I created a new directory and I'm trying to register an app in the active directory, but when I try to configure an app, not all options appear (left menu), like App Roles.

Is it some configuration that's missing? if I force the app roles link in the browser, it even briefly shows the menus and then they disappear.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it some configuration that's missing? if I force the app roles link in the browser, it even briefly shows the menus and then they disappear.

To view the **App Roles** and **Administrators options** in the **Azure portal**, you need to have **Application administrator** or **Cloud application administrator** role assigned to your account.

You can assign **Cloud application administrator** role to user by follwing steps.

**Go to Azure portal > Azure Active Directory > Enterprise applications > Select your application > Roles and administrators > Cloud Application Administrator > Add assignment > Setting > under Assignment type(Active)**

[image]

Once the role is assigned to the user account, you should be able to see all the options in the left menu, including **App roles** and **Administrators**.

[image]

Reference:  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/roles/delegate-app-roles.md

Comment: In this flow that you showed, 'Roles and Administrators' does not appear. And I think I shouldn't even do that, since I own the directory and the applications. that doesn't make sense. I found another way to add myself to these roles, but it didn't help. I still don't see these options in the menu.

Comment: If you are the owner of the directory and the application, then you should have the necessary permissions to access all the options in the Azure portal.
You can try logging out and logging back into the Azure portal. If that doesn't work, you can try clearing your browser cache or using a different browser.

Comment: I've already done all that. This problem only occurs with new directories. surely, something is missing so that it stays the same as the original directory.